# Retrieving JSON in Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, wcf

I have recently started working on WebServices and I don't completely know if it is even possible. I am passing JSON string to WCF Web Service and I want to know if there is anyway that Web Service can retrieve JSON string and return data against the retrieved string?

Comment: I dont know much about WCF but you can try json serializing\deserializing.Do some research for Newtonsoft.Json and its serializers they may help.

Comment: Alright. I'll let you know whatever I find out. Thank you

Comment: If your goal is solely to build an Http based service, WebApi (http://www.asp.net/web-api) is probably an easier option than wcf

Comment: Can I use the mentioned method through WebApi?

Comment: an operation that takes a string in parameter and returns a string? of course you can

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're just passing a string to your WCS service.

That string contains JSON, so it needs to be parsed to retrieve the content.

There are several ways to parse JSON in .NET, I will just link a few of them, but you can find several more online:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh770289.aspx
- http://www.masnun.com/2011/07/08/quick-json-parsing-with-c-sharp.html
- http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate a little further? I just need to know how to get my service to retrieve JSON instead of getting values from URL. I am already passing JSON to service. I don't know how to retrieve it from service.

Comment: In which way are you passing the JSON to the service?

Comment: I add the service to references and create its object. I am passing the JSON later on but I am getting this error now while initializing an object of the class.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll